petalinux-build fails with automake-native-1.16.3-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
I'm trying to run petalinux-build and it gives the error
automake-native-1.16.3-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
Here's the full log
ERROR: automake-native-1.16.3-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: automake-native-1.16.3-r0 do_compile: ExecutionError('/home/pdev/xilinx-zcu102-2022.2/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.16.3-r0/temp/run.do_compile.32721', 1, None, None)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/pdev/xilinx-zcu102-2022.2/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.16.3-r0/temp/log.do_compile.32721
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function autotools_aclocals
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'bit-64', 'x86_64-linux', 'common']
| DEBUG: Python function autotools_aclocals finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_compile
| NOTE: make -j 4
| : && /home/pdev/xilinx-zcu102-2022.2/build/tmp/hosttools/mkdir -p doc && ./pre-inst-env /usr/bin/env perl ../automake-1.16.3/doc/help2man --output=doc/aclocal-1.16.1 aclocal-1.16
| : && /home/pdev/xilinx-zcu102-2022.2/build/tmp/hosttools/mkdir -p doc && ./pre-inst-env /usr/bin/env perl ../automake-1.16.3/doc/help2man --output=doc/automake-1.16.1 automake-1.16 --no-discard-stderr
| Can't locate Text/Tabs.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Text::Tabs module) (@INC contains: /home/pdev/xilinx-zcu102-2022.2/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.16.3-r0/build/lib/ /home/pdev/xilinx-zcu102-2022.2/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.16.3-r0/build/../automake-1.16.3/lib/ /opt/pkg/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/bin/../..//usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/x86_64-linux /opt/pkg/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/bin/../..//usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0 /opt/pkg/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/bin/../..//usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.34.0 /opt/pkg/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/bin/../..//usr/lib/perl5/5.34.0/x86_64-linux /opt/pkg/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/bin/../..//usr/lib/perl5/5.34.0 /usr/local/oe-sdk-hardcoded-buildpath/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/oe-sdk-hardcoded-buildpath/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0 /usr/local/oe-sdk-hardcoded-buildpath/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.34.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/oe-sdk-hardcoded-buildpath/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.34.0 /usr/local/oe-sdk-hardcoded-buildpath/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/lib/perl5/5.34.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/oe-sdk-hardcoded-buildpath/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/lib/perl5/5.34.0) at ../automake-1.16.3/doc/help2man line 26.
| BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ../automake-1.16.3/doc/help2man line 26.
| make: *** [Makefile:3749: doc/automake-1.16.1] Error 2
| make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
| Can't locate Text/Tabs.pm in @INC (you may need to install the Text::Tabs module) (@INC contains: /home/pdev/xilinx-zcu102-2022.2/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.16.3-r0/build/lib/ /home/pdev/xilinx-zcu102-2022.2/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.16.3-r0/build/../automake-1.16.3/lib/ /opt/pkg/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/bin/../..//usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/x86_64-linux /opt/pkg/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/bin/../..//usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0 /opt/pkg/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/bin/../..//usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.34.0 /opt/pkg/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/bin/../..//usr/lib/perl5/5.34.0/x86_64-linux /opt/pkg/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/bin/../..//usr/lib/perl5/5.34.0 /usr/local/oe-sdk-hardcoded-buildpath/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/oe-sdk-hardcoded-buildpath/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.34.0 /usr/local/oe-sdk-hardcoded-buildpath/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.34.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/oe-sdk-hardcoded-buildpath/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.34.0 /usr/local/oe-sdk-hardcoded-buildpath/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/lib/perl5/5.34.0/x86_64-linux /usr/local/oe-sdk-hardcoded-buildpath/sysroots/x86_64-petalinux-linux/usr/lib/perl5/5.34.0) at ../automake-1.16.3/doc/help2man line 26.
| BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ../automake-1.16.3/doc/help2man line 26.
| ERROR: oe_runmake failed
| WARNING: /home/pdev/xilinx-zcu102-2022.2/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.16.3-r0/temp/run.do_compile.32721:187 exit 1 from 'exit 1'
| WARNING: Backtrace (BB generated script):
| make: *** [Makefile:3747: doc/aclocal-1.16.1] Error 2
|       #1: bbfatal_log, /home/pdev/xilinx-zcu102-2022.2/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.16.3-r0/temp/run.do_compile.32721, line 187
|       #2: die, /home/pdev/xilinx-zcu102-2022.2/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.16.3-r0/temp/run.do_compile.32721, line 171
|       #3: oe_runmake, /home/pdev/xilinx-zcu102-2022.2/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.16.3-r0/temp/run.do_compile.32721, line 166
|       #4: autotools_do_compile, /home/pdev/xilinx-zcu102-2022.2/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.16.3-r0/temp/run.do_compile.32721, line 161
|       #5: do_compile, /home/pdev/xilinx-zcu102-2022.2/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.16.3-r0/temp/run.do_compile.32721, line 156
|       #6: main, /home/pdev/xilinx-zcu102-2022.2/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/automake-native/1.16.3-r0/temp/run.do_compile.32721, line 200
ERROR: Task (virtual:native:/home/pdev/xilinx-zcu102-2022.2/components/yocto/layers/core/meta/recipes-devtools/automake/automake_1.16.3.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'

I've updated the automake to the version 1.16.5
I run cpan Text::Tabs to install module

This appears to be an issue inside the build recipe which builds automake: It should have made sure that the Perl package/module (I forget what Perl calls those) Text::Tabs is installed before trying to build automake.
